# list of logged in users who recieved wall message in Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line

Is there a way to get the list of logged in users (With a terminal open) who recieved wall message in Linux.

Comment: Try `w` command. Please see: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-list-current-logged-in-users/